# how to make a join of 3 tables in JPA?

Tags: sql, jpa

I want to make a join of 3 tables in JPA.
here are the 3 tables:

- USER [(pk) userId, login, password];
- TASK [(pk) taskId, taskname, start, end, #userId];
- TASK_USER [(cmp) taskId, (cmp) userId];

here is the SQL query to execute in JPA:

```
SELECT tu.taskId, t.start, t.end 
  FROM task as t, 
       user as u, 
       task_user as tu 
 WHERE (tu.taskId = t.taskId 
   AND tu.userId = u.userId 
   AND t.userId = u.userId) 
   AND tu.userId = '2';
```

But the ones that pose me problem are the syntaxes to write on the request of the JPA.

Can you help me?

Comment: JPA uses entities (classes) not tables. Define the classes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tu.taskId, t.start, t.end 
FROM task as t, user as u, task_user as tu 
WHERE tu.taskId = t.taskId AND tu.userId = u.userId 
      AND t.userId = u.userId 
      AND tu.userId = '2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT tu.taskId, t.start, t.end FROM task as t inner join user as u
on u.userId = t.userId inner join task_user as tu on tu.taskId = t.taskId
where tu.userId = '2';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have define the relation between your entity with a relation ManyToMany
Check this if not https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

You can write this kind of query

```
SELECT t.taskId, t.start, t.end FROM User as u left join u.tasks WHERE u.userId = '2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it's OK. I can write a query as SQL in JPA. the syntax is same that SQL and I can return an Object for exemple: User object in join